# Reference on the history of ergodic theory

Tags: math-history, ergodic-theory

I'm looking for some good books on the history of ergodic theory. I'm a Ph.D student in the field, and I am taking Steven Weinberg's advice to learn about the history of my field:

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/nature.pdf

My background is in physics as an undergraduate, so any references that are heavy on thermodynamics and statistical physics are welcome. A good reference on ergodic theory must include these subjects, in my opinion.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is hard to come by a historical account of ergodic theory on its own, instead any such account will be on dynamics (or "dynamics & ergodic theory", depending on your personal convictions). Keeping this in mind there are a few nice resources I believe (as a disclaimer I will also include some popular mathematics/science books as well):

1. *Chaos: Making a New Science* by James Gleick
2. *Philosophy and the Foundations of Dynamics* by Lawrence Sklar
3. *The Recursive Universe: Cosmic Complexity and the Limits of Scientific Knowledge* by William Poundstone
4. The documentary *[Chaos](http://www.chaos-math.org/en)* by Jos Leys, Étienne Ghys and Aurélien Alvarez
5. [Historical accounts](http://personal.psu.edu/axk29/history.html) of Anatole Katok
6. [First section](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jack/DYNOTES/dn1.pdf) of John Milnor's lecture notes on dynamics, and the [references](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jack/DYNOTES/dnR.pdf) therein.